# read line after specific delimiter

Tags: vb.net

My problem is I dont understand how to output in lblBoxes proper data from txt.file
I have 8 lbloutputs in my form and I am trying to trim everything including :. 
This not working and I understand that it is finding index of : in a first line but sub string using this in second line. I was also thinking to create Array to find all indexes first and then use them with sub string but it does not let me at list in a way I am doing this. Example of array:

```
    'EXAMPLE OF BAD ARRAY
    Dim intIndexDelimiter() As Integer

    For Each i As Integer In employeeDataFileInput.ReadToEnd.IndexOf(":")
        intIndexDelimiter = i
    Next
```

Code:

```
    Public Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strFileName As String                        'hold name fo the file
        Dim employeeDataFileInput As StreamReader        'object variable

        'get name for file
         strFileName = InputBox("Enter Name Of the File", "Open File")

        If File.Exists(strFileName) Then
        'open file 
        employeeDataFileInput = File.OpenText(strFileName)
        MessageBox.Show(strFileName & "File open")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(strFileName & "This file does not exist.")
    End If

    'not working 
    lblRecordNum.Text = CStr(employeeDataFileInput.ReadLine.Substring(employeeDataFileInput.ReadLine.IndexOf(":")))
End Sub
```

My txt file data

```
Record Number: 1
First Name: Tim
Middle Name: K
Last Name: Black
Employee Number: 111
Phone Number: 1112223344
Extention: 1
Email: sv@gmail.com
Department: Accounting

Record Number: 2
First Name: Jim
Middle Name: K
Last Name: Fisher
Employee Number: 222
Phone Number: 2223334455
Extention: 2
Email: jf@gmail.com
Department: Administration

Record Number: 3
First Name: James
Middle Name: T
Last Name: Holt
Employee Number: 333
Phone Number: 3334445566
Extention: 3
Email: jh@gmail.com
Department: Sales
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Here is an example of reading a file and displaying the data read from an input like the one you have. The key point is to use split method to separate the input arround the ":".

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Namespace Console_Work
    Class Program

        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim FileName As String = "C:\temp\MyIOFile.txt"
            If Not File.Exists(FileName) Then
                Console.WriteLine("*** Error {0} does not exist. Please hit any keu", FileName)
                Console.Read()
                Return
            End If
            Dim inputRecord As [String]
            Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(FileName)

                While (InlineAssignHelper(inputRecord, sr.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
                    'Process read record
                    ProcessInputRecord(inputRecord)
                End While
                Console.WriteLine("The end of the stream has been reached.")
            End Using
            Console.WriteLine("End - Please hit any key")
            Console.Read()
        End Sub

        '------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Public Shared Sub ProcessInputRecord(parm_record As String)

            Dim fldValue As String() = New String(0) {}
            Try
                fldValue = parm_record.Split(New [Char]() {":"C})
                If fldValue.GetUpperBound(0) = 1 Then
                    'the header text will be in fldvalue[0] and the data will be in fldValue[1]
                    Console.WriteLine("Header=" & fldValue(0) & vbTab & vbTab & "Data=" & fldValue(1))
                        'logic comes here when there is no :
                Else
                                '//logic comes here when there is no : in the input line
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

                Console.WriteLine("***Error parsing:" & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & parm_record)
            End Try

        End Sub
        Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
            target = value
            Return value
        End Function



    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Split Method of String for spliting the line into key/value pairs.

I mean: Your read the complete line and split it.